# python scapy using incorrect egress interface

Tags: python, routes, scapy

I have two interfaces with default gateway. wlan0 is my wireless and tun0 is my VPN connection (using that wireless as a transport).
When VPN session is established wlan0 metric is increased to 20 - that is why default via VPN should be used.

```
pluton ~ # ip route show
default dev tun0  scope link 
default via 10.0.0.1 dev wlan0  metric 20
```

But it seems that scapy is trying to send L3 packets (send() function) using wlan0.

Could you confirm ? I could not find any bug related with that behavior.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question? Is the metric increased after `scapy` is imported?

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the usage for [Scapy's `send()` function](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#sending-packets) you will see an option for an interface to use specified by `iface`.

```
sendp("I'm travelling on Ethernet", iface="eth1", loop=1, inter=0.2)
```

I am unsure what the default behavior is for `sendp()`, but if you specify the interface, it should solve your problem.

Comment: sendp() is used for L2 - not L3. When using sendp() i would need to prepare ethernet packet myself (check routing etc.). Still i can not find easy way to check routing and compare metric to choose the correct one :( it looks like a scapy bug - a workaround for this is to add /32 route for our destination pointing via tunnel interface.

Comment: On my system `send()` correctly routes packets. Not sure why it wouldn't on yours. What does your wlan0 look like?

Comment: As explained it does not route correctly when having two default routes. Having two default routes is typical when having VPN (tun interface). Then old default route has increased metric (wlan0 with metric 20 in my example) which should force linux to use new default route via VPN (metric = 0) instead of old one. And it works fine for system/applications - except scapy.

Comment: Your other question I posted an answer that will be relevant to this one. If you want to report a Scapy bug, try https://bitbucket.org/secdev/scapy/issues?status=new&status=open

Comment: Scapy seems to get confused now and then about routes, seems that IPv6 is especially challenging. I used sendp(iface="..."), to make the packet ethernet a simple Ether()/IP... is enough